# C# linq - dynamic tabcontrol with dynamic buttons and labels

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following db:[Db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrxXe.png).
I want to create a Point of sale. 
I want a tab for each db.category, in each tab I want a label for each db.product and in the same label row I want a button for each db.size with a button value = db.price.
Who can help me, please?

```
        using (var db = new GelatoProjectDBEntities())
        {

            var prodotti = (from x in db.ProductsLists
                            select new { x.Id, x.Category, x.Product, x.Size, x.Price}
                            ).ToArray();

            var categories = (from x in prodotti
                              select x.Category)
                              .Distinct();
            var products = (from x in prodotti
                            select x.Product)
                            .Distinct();
            var sizes = (from x in prodotti
                         select x.Size);

            foreach (var category in categories)
            {
                TabPage TabProduct = new TabPage(category);
                TabProduct.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                foreach (var product in prodotti.Where(x => x.Category == category).Distinct())
                {
                    var label = new Label();
                    label.Text = product.Product;
                    label.Location=new Point(posXlabel, posYlabel);
                    TabProduct.Controls.Add(label);

                    foreach (var size in prodotti.Where(x => x.Product == product.ToString()))
                    {
                        var button = new Button();
                        button.Text = product.Size;
                        button.Size = new Size(100, 50);
                        button.Location = new Point(posXbutton, posYbutton);
                        button.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
                        button.Click += Button_Click;
                        TabProduct.Controls.Add(button);
                        posXbutton = posXbutton + gapXbutton;
                    }
                }
                posYbutton = posYbutton + gapYbutton;
                tabControl1.TabPages.Add(TabProduct);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: post updated I'm sorry

Comment: @Mirko Still no winforms/wpf/asp tag... C# linq is not what we mean....

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm doing this as hobby and I'm new of this website so I don't understand...I'm programming on Visual Studio